# How to do Stratified sampling with Spark DataFrames?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm in Spark 1.3.0 and my data is in DataFrames.
I need operations like sampleByKey(), sampleByKeyExact().
I saw the JIRA "Add approximate stratified sampling to DataFrame" (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7157).
That's targeted for Spark 1.5, till that comes through, whats the easiest way to accomplish the equivalent of sampleByKey() and sampleByKeyExact() on DataFrames.
Thanks & Regards
MK

Answer (score 4):

Spark 1.1 [added](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/08/27/statistics-functionality-in-spark.html) stratified sampling routines `SampleByKey` and `SampleByKeyExact` to Spark Core, so since then they are available without MLLib dependencies.

These two functions are `PairRDDFunctions` and belong to key-value `RDD[(K,T)]`. Also DataFrames do not have keys. You'd have to use underlying RDD - something like below:

```
val df = ... // your dataframe
val fractions: Map[K, Double] = ... // specify the exact fraction desired from each key

val sample = df.rdd.keyBy(x=>x(0)).sampleByKey(false, fractions)
```

Note that `sample` is RDD not DataFrame now, but you can easily convert it back to DataFrame since you already have schema defined for `df`.