# PySpark sampleBy using multiple columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to carry out a stratified sampling from a data frame on PySpark. There is a `sampleBy(col, fractions, seed=None)` function, but it seems to only use one column as a strata. Is there any way to use multiple columns as a strata?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193800/how-to-do-stratified-sampling-with-spark-dataframes)

after converting it to python, I think an answer might look like:

```
#create a dataframe to use
df = sc.parallelize([ (1,1234,282),(1,1396,179),(2,8620,178),(3,1620,191),(3,8820,828) ] ).toDF(["ID","X","Y"])

#we are going to use the first two columns as our key (strata)
#assign sampling percentages to each key # you could do something cooler here
fractions = df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1])).distinct().map(lambda x: (x,0.3)).collectAsMap()

#setup how we want to key the dataframe
kb = df.rdd.keyBy(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))

#create a dataframe after sampling from our newly keyed rdd
#note, if the sample did not return any values you'll get a `ValueError: RDD is empty` error

sampleddf = kb.sampleByKey(False,fractions).map(lambda x: x[1]).toDF(df.columns)
sampleddf.show()
+---+----+---+
| ID|   X|  Y|
+---+----+---+
|  1|1234|282|
|  1|1396|179|
|  3|1620|191|
+---+----+---+
#other examples
kb.sampleByKey(False,fractions).map(lambda x: x[1]).toDF(df.columns).show()
+---+----+---+
| ID|   X|  Y|
+---+----+---+
|  2|8620|178|
+---+----+---+


kb.sampleByKey(False,fractions).map(lambda x: x[1]).toDF(df.columns).show()
+---+----+---+
| ID|   X|  Y|
+---+----+---+
|  1|1234|282|
|  1|1396|179|
+---+----+---+
```

Is this the kind of thing you were looking for?

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for. I wanted to change the sample fractions for different keys, but it will be trivial after looking at this.

Comment: Also there's a typo on your 2nd line `sc.parallelize([] ...`

Answer (score 0):

James Tobin's solution above works fine with the example presented but I had difficulties replicating the approach on my dataset (nearly 2 million records). Strange java related runtime error occured and I was not able to pinpoint what the issue was (I was running pyspark in local mode).

An alternative approach would be to flex the approach of stratified sampling based on a single column. For this, we create a new (temporary) column which is a merger of the values present in the multiple columns on which we originally wanted to apply stratified sampling. Then, we perform the splits and delete the `merged column` in the resulting splits.

```
def get_stratified_split_multiple_columns(input_df, col_name1, col_name2, seed_value=1234, train_frac=0.6):
    """
    Following the approach of stratified sampling based on a single column as
    presented at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47672336/530399 .
    However, this time our single column is going to be a merger
    of the values present in multiple columns (`col_name1` and `col_name2`).

    Note that pyspark split is not exact. Therefore, if there are too few 
    examples per category, it can be that none of the examples go to 
    validation/test split and therefore result in error.
    """

    merged_col_name = "both_labels"
    input_df = input_df.withColumn(merged_col_name, F.concat(F.col(col_name1), F.lit('_#_@_#_'),
                                                             F.col(col_name2)))  # The "_#_@_#_" acts as a separator between the values.
    
    fractions1 = input_df.select(merged_col_name).distinct().withColumn("fraction",
                                                                        F.lit(train_frac)).rdd.collectAsMap()
    train_df = input_df.stat.sampleBy(merged_col_name, fractions1, seed_value)

    valid_and_test_df = input_df.exceptAll(train_df)
    fractions2 = {key: 0.5 for key, value in fractions1.items()}  # 0.5 for equal split of valid and test set

    valid_df = valid_and_test_df.stat.sampleBy(merged_col_name, fractions2, seed_value)
    test_df = valid_and_test_df.exceptAll(valid_df)

    # Delete the merged_col_name from all splits
    train_df = train_df.drop(merged_col_name)
    valid_df = valid_df.drop(merged_col_name)
    test_df = test_df.drop(merged_col_name)

    return train_df, valid_df, test_df
```