# Stratified sampling with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark `DataFrame` that has one column that has **lots of zeros** and very few ones (only 0.01% of ones).

I'd like to take a random subsample but a stratified one - so that it keeps the ratio of 1s to 0s in that column.

Is it possible to do in pyspark ?

I am looking for a **non-scala** solution and on based on `DataFrame`s and not `RDD`-based.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The solution I suggested in [Stratified sampling in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32241887/3415409)
 is pretty straightforward to convert from **Scala** to **Python** (or even to **Java** - [What's the easiest way to stratify a Spark Dataset ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41676846/3415409)).

Nevertheless, I'll rewrite it **python**. Let's start first by creating a toy `DataFrame` :

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
list = [(2147481832,23355149,1),(2147481832,973010692,1),(2147481832,2134870842,1),(2147481832,541023347,1),(2147481832,1682206630,1),(2147481832,1138211459,1),(2147481832,852202566,1),(2147481832,201375938,1),(2147481832,486538879,1),(2147481832,919187908,1),(214748183,919187908,1),(214748183,91187908,1)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(list, ["x1","x2","x3"])
df.show()
# +----------+----------+---+
# |        x1|        x2| x3|
# +----------+----------+---+
# |2147481832|  23355149|  1|
# |2147481832| 973010692|  1|
# |2147481832|2134870842|  1|
# |2147481832| 541023347|  1|
# |2147481832|1682206630|  1|
# |2147481832|1138211459|  1|
# |2147481832| 852202566|  1|
# |2147481832| 201375938|  1|
# |2147481832| 486538879|  1|
# |2147481832| 919187908|  1|
# | 214748183| 919187908|  1|
# | 214748183|  91187908|  1|
# +----------+----------+---+
```

This `DataFrame` has 12 elements as you can see :

```python
df.count()
# 12
```

Distributed as followed :

```python
df.groupBy("x1").count().show()
# +----------+-----+
# |        x1|count|
# +----------+-----+
# |2147481832|   10|
# | 214748183|    2|
# +----------+-----+
```

Now let's sample :

First we'll set the seed :

```python
seed = 12
```

The find the keys to fraction on and sample :

```python
fractions = df.select("x1").distinct().withColumn("fraction", lit(0.8)).rdd.collectAsMap()
print(fractions)                                                            
# {2147481832: 0.8, 214748183: 0.8}
sampled_df = df.stat.sampleBy("x1", fractions, seed)
sampled_df.show()
# +----------+---------+---+
# |        x1|       x2| x3|
# +----------+---------+---+
# |2147481832| 23355149|  1|
# |2147481832|973010692|  1|
# |2147481832|541023347|  1|
# |2147481832|852202566|  1|
# |2147481832|201375938|  1|
# |2147481832|486538879|  1|
# |2147481832|919187908|  1|
# | 214748183|919187908|  1|
# | 214748183| 91187908|  1|
# +----------+---------+---+
```

We can now check the content of our sample :

```python
sampled_df.count()
# 9

sampled_df.groupBy("x1").count().show()
# +----------+-----+
# |        x1|count|
# +----------+-----+
# |2147481832|    7|
# | 214748183|    2|
# +----------+-----+
```

Comment: @eliasah is there any way to add 0.8 and 0.2 fractions? I want to use 0.8 as training set and the other 0.2 as test set. I tried to get the 0.8 using this approach but have difficulties getting the other 0.2 in spark 1.6 where there is no sub query support

Comment: You can always use `except` on the main DF and the sampled DF @EmmaNej

Comment: @eliasah  Yeah but that would take a long time considering that I have 20 Million records and no unique key in the dataset.

Comment: @EmmaNej Then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887526/filter-spark-dataframe-based-on-another-dataframe-that-specifies-blacklist-crite/39889263#39889263

Comment: @eliasah unfortunately Spark 1.6 does not support left_anti join.

Comment: @eliasah I get that 0.8 here is the variable sampling rates for different keys. the question is how can I choose this value for 12 different keys or classes

Comment: It already take into account different classes/keys. We need a stratified sample according to the column `x1`, so we create a map of keys and what is the fraction of the key we need and we ask spark to give fractionned data by key.

Comment: so the choice of the 0.8 value is determined by maximum_value(df.groupBy("x1").count().show())/df.count(). is that correct ?

Comment: No. I've decided that I need 80% of my data stratified. Thus the 0.8 i.e `lit(0.8)`. If I needed 70%, I'd have used 0.7... I advice you to read my answer for the scala API (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238727/stratified-sampling-in-spark/32241887#32241887) The explanation is more complete there.

Comment: ah okey, I see. Thank you for the clarifícation :)

Answer (score 25):

Assume you have titanic dataset in 'data' dataframe which you want to split into train and test set using stratified sampling based on the 'Survived' target variable.

```
  # Check initial distributions of 0's and 1's
-> data.groupBy("Survived").count().show()

 Survived|count|
 +--------+-----+
 |       1|  342|
 |       0|  549


  # Taking 70% of both 0's and 1's into training set
-> train = data.sampleBy("Survived", fractions={0: 0.7, 1: 0.7}, seed=10)

  # Subtracting 'train' from original 'data' to get test set 
-> test = data.subtract(train)



  # Checking distributions of 0's and 1's in train and test sets after the sampling
-> train.groupBy("Survived").count().show()
+--------+-----+
|Survived|count|
+--------+-----+
|       1|  239|
|       0|  399|
+--------+-----+
-> test.groupBy("Survived").count().show()

+--------+-----+
|Survived|count|
+--------+-----+
|       1|  103|
|       0|  150|
+--------+-----+
```

Comment: Code may look cleaner and smaller but `subtract` function takes very long to run. Answer shared below is faster : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61016937/8357062

Answer (score 7):

This can be accomplished pretty easily with 'randomSplit' and 'union' in PySpark.

```
# read in data
df = spark.read.csv(file, header=True)
# split dataframes between 0s and 1s
zeros = df.filter(df["Target"]==0)
ones = df.filter(df["Target"]==1)
# split datasets into training and testing
train0, test0 = zeros.randomSplit([0.8,0.2], seed=1234)
train1, test1 = ones.randomSplit([0.8,0.2], seed=1234)
# stack datasets back together
train = train0.union(train1)
test = test0.union(test1)
```

Answer (score 5):

this is based on the accepted answer of @eliasah and [this so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39889263/1771155)

If you want to get back a train and testset you can use the following function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 

def stratified_split_train_test(df, frac, label, join_on, seed=42):
    """ stratfied split of a dataframe in train and test set.
    inspiration gotten from:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/47672336/1771155
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/39889263/1771155"""
    fractions = df.select(label).distinct().withColumn("fraction", F.lit(frac)).rdd.collectAsMap()
    df_frac = df.stat.sampleBy(label, fractions, seed)
    df_remaining = df.join(df_frac, on=join_on, how="left_anti")
    return df_frac, df_remaining
```

to create a stratified train and test set where 80% of the total is used for the training set

```
df_train, df_test = stratified_split_train_test(df=df, frac=0.8, label="y", join_on="unique_id")
```

Comment: I do not have a 'unique_id' columns in my dataset. Is there a way this function can be re-written?

Comment: @BehzadRowshanravan https://stackoverflow.com/a/72379515/8231475

Comment: @BehzadRowshanravan I'm passing my `df` to this function and expect to return `df_train, df_val, df_test` but surprisingly I can't `display(df_train)`. due to this error: *NameError: name 'df_train' is not defined*. Why it is the case in databricks?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below function. I used the other answers to combine.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame as SparkDataFrame


def train_test_split_pyspark(
    df: SparkDataFrame,
    startify_column: str,
    unique_col: str = None,
    train_fraction: float = 0.05,
    validation_fraction: float = 0.005,
    test_fraction: float = 0.005,
    seed: int = 1234,
    to_pandas: bool = True,
):
    if not unique_col:
        unique_col = "any_unique_name_here"
        df = df.withColumn(unique_col, f.monotonically_increasing_id())

    # Train data
    train_fraction_dict = (
        df.select(startify_column)
        .distinct()
        .withColumn("fraction", f.lit(train_fraction))
        .rdd.collectAsMap()
    )
    df_train = df.stat.sampleBy(startify_column, train_fraction_dict, seed)
    df_remaining = df.join(df_train, on=unique_col, how="left_anti")

    # Validation data
    validation_fraction_dict = {
        key: validation_fraction for (_, key) in enumerate(train_fraction_dict)
    }
    df_val = df_remaining.stat.sampleBy(startify_column, validation_fraction_dict, seed)
    df_remaining = df_remaining.join(df_val, on=unique_col, how="left_anti")

    # Test data
    test_fraction_dict = {
        key: test_fraction for (_, key) in enumerate(train_fraction_dict)
    }
    df_test = df_remaining.stat.sampleBy(startify_column, test_fraction_dict, seed)

    if unique_col == "any_unique_name_here":
        df_train = df_train.drop(unique_col)
        df_val = df_val.drop(unique_col)
        df_test = df_test.drop(unique_col)

    if to_pandas:
        return (df_train.toPandas(), df_val.toPandas(), df_test.toPandas())
    return df_train, df_val, df_test
```

Comment: I'm passing my `df` to this function and expect to return `df_train, df_val, df_test` but surprisingly I can't `display(df_train)`. due to this error: *NameError: name 'df_train' is not defined*. Why it is the case in databricks?

Comment: Hi @Mario I assume you deactivated the `to_pandas` variable. Do you get the return as a tuple of three items?

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

list = [(2147481832,23355149,'v0'),(2147481832,973010692,'v3'), 
(2147481832,2134870842,'v1'),(2147481832,541023347,'v3'), 
(2147481832,1682206630,'v2'),(2147481832,1138211459,'v4'), 
(2147481832,852202566,'v2'),(2147481832,201375938,'v5'), 
(2147481832,486538879,'v3'),(2147481832,919187908,'v4'), 
(214748183,919187908,'v3'),(214748183,91187908,'v4')]

df = spark.createDataFrame(list, ["x1","x2","x3"])

df = df.sampleBy("x3", fractions={'v1': 0.2, 'v2': 
0.2, 'v3': 0.2,'v4':0.2,'v5':0.2}, seed=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid rows found in both train/test split or disappearing, I would further add to Vincent Claes’s solution

```
def stratifiedSampler(sparkDf:DataFrame, ratio:float, 
                     label:str, joinOn:str, seed=42):

        fractions = (sparkDf.select(label).distinct()
                           .withColumn("fraction",f.lit(ratio))
                           .rdd.collectAsMap())

        fracDf = sparkDf.stat.sampleBy(label, fractions, seed)
        fracDf = fracDf.localCheckpoint()
        
        remaingDf = sparkDf.join(fracDf, on=joinOn, how="left_anti")
        return (fracDf, remaingDf)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to stratified sampling by more than one column you can compute each sample probability inside the full dataset and multiply the fraction. Then, use rand() function to random select the samples.

The following code preserves the data distribution along the stratum and sample a proportion of your data.

```py
PERCENTAGE_SAMPLE = 0.80 # This is the fraction to keep
STRATUM_VARIABLES = ['x1', 'x3', 'x7']

# Create a window for your stratum
window_stratified = W.Window.partitionBy(*STRATUM_VARIABLES)

df_sample = (df
             # Compute each sample's probability in dataset
            .withColumn("num_rows", F.count('*').over(window_stratified))
            .withColumn("total_samples_dataset", F.count('*').over(W.Window.partitionBy()))
            .withColumn('sample_proba', F.col('num_rows')/F.col('total_samples_dataset'))
            
            # Each sample will weight inversely
            .withColumn('weight_sample', (F.lit(1.)-F.col('sample_proba')) *  F.lit(PERCENTAGE_SAMPLE))

            # Sample
            .filter(F.rand(seed=42) <= F.col('weight_sample'))
)

# Log info de reduction in data
nrows_original = df.count()
nrows_sample = df_sample.count()
proportion = nrows_sample/nrows_original
print(f'[{nrows_original}] -> [{nrows_sample}]. Reduction = [{100*proportion:.1f}]%')
```