# Pyspark random split changes distribution of data

Tags: python, pyspark

I found a very strange behavior with pyspark when I use `randomSplit`. I have a column `is_clicked` that takes values `0` or `1` and there are way more zeros than ones. After random split I would expect the data would be uniformly distributed. But instead, I see that the first rows in the splits are all `is_cliked=1`, followed by rows that are all `is_clicked=0`. You can see that number of clicks in the original dataframe `df` is 9 out of 1000 (which is what I expect). But after random split the number of clicks is 1000 out of 1000. If I take more rows I will see that it's all going to be `is_clicked=1` until there are no more columns like this, and then it will be followed by rows `is_clicked=0`.

Anyone knows why there is distribution change after random split? How can I make `is_clicked` be uniformly distributed after split?

[image]

Comment: it is "random" split.  It only takes care of splitting records to the specified weight regardless of column values.  Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637760/stratified-sampling-with-pyspark for stratified sampling.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, but I do need random splitting, and it's not. For some reason, it gives me the first rows to be the ones with `is_clicked=1`, while it should not be the case.

Comment: can you provide sample dataset (1000 records)

Comment: Spark dataframe is distributed across multiple partitions and not ordered. unless with `sort` or `orderBy`, you won't guarantee to have same ordering after a function. Maybe that's what is seeing?

Comment: So, if your original dataframe has `is_clicked=1` more than 1000, it is *possible* to be like your result.  Do you know how many records you have in total and how many are `is_clicked=1`?

Comment: @Emma see the problem and the solution below.

Answer (score 2):

So indeed pyspark **does** sort the data, when does randomSplit. Here is a quote from [the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2536):

> It is possible that the underlying dataframe doesn't guarantee the
> ordering of rows in its constituent partitions each time a split is
> materialized which could result in  overlapping splits. To prevent
> this, we explicitly sort each input partition to make the ordering
> deterministic. Note that MapTypes cannot be sorted and are explicitly
> pruned out from the sort order.

The solution to this either reshuffle the data after the split or just use `filter` instead of `randomSplit`:

Solution 1:

```
df = df.withColumn('rand', sf.rand(seed=42)).orderBy('rand')
df_train, df_test = df.randomSplit([0.5, 0.5])
df_train.orderBy('rand')
```

Solution 2:

```
df_train = df.filter(df.rand < 0.5)
df_test = df.filter(df.rand >= 0.5)
```

Here is [a blog post](https://sergei-ivanov.medium.com/why-you-should-not-use-randomsplit-in-pyspark-to-split-data-into-train-and-test-58576d539a36) with more details.

Comment: oh very interesting! I didn't know `randomSplit` works in that way.  Nice medium post as well!  Thank you.