# How can I sampleBy a date column without casting it to another type in PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a data frame which I'd like to sample by its date column. However, `sampleBy` will only accept float, int, or str types:

```py
from datetime import date
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# create dummy data
df_rows = [Row(date = date(2020, 1, d), value=d*2) for d in range(1,31)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(df_rows)

df.show(5)
+----------+-----+
|      date|value|
+----------+-----+
|2020-01-01|    2|
|2020-01-02|    4|
|2020-01-03|    6|
|2020-01-04|    8|
|2020-01-05|   10|
+----------+-----+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Following [this SO approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47672336/13258525) I get the following error:

```
fractions = (df
    .select("date")
    .distinct()
    .withColumn("fraction", F.lit(1.0))
    .rdd.collectAsMap()
)

sampled_df = df.sampleBy("date", fractions, seed=42)
```

> PySparkTypeError: [DISALLOWED_TYPE_FOR_CONTAINER] Argument `fractions`(type: dict) should only contain a type in [float, int, str], got date

I tried formatting the dictionary values as strings, but this then didn't match the original columns, and my sampled dataframe was empty:

```py
fractions = (df
    .select(F.date_format(F.col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd" ))
    .distinct()
    .withColumn("fraction", lit(1.0))
    .rdd.collectAsMap()
)
sampled_df = df.sampleBy("date", fractions, seed=42)

sampled_df.groupBy("date").count().show()
+----+-----+
|date|count|
+----+-----+
+----+-----+
```

If I cast the original column to string first, I can then sample, but I'm hoping to avoid this partly to keep the code simple, and partly for computational speed:

```
sampled_df = (df
    .withColumn("date", F.date_format(F.col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd" ))
    .sampleBy("date", fractions, seed=42)
)

sampled_df.groupBy("date").count().show(5)
+----------+-----+
|      date|count|
+----------+-----+
|2020-01-02|    1|
|2020-01-06|    1|
|2020-01-03|    1|
|2020-01-07|    1|
|2020-01-10|    1|
+----------+-----+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Is it possible to sampleBy a column that isn't float, int or str type without the intermediate casting step?

Comment: You can convert it into an integer using `F.unix_timestamp()`. Another option would be to provide a schema where the date column's datatype is provided as `StringType`.

Comment: Thanks user238607. Converting to integer would be better than to string, but I'm trying to avoid them if it's possible (hence the question).

Comment: `df.sampleBy(F.date_format('date', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), fractions, seed=42)`? It still does casting inline but won't save it to a column.